# How to share data in between components which don't have any relation?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here i want to pass **lastUpdatedTime** from `from component` to the `to component` which don't have any relationship.

```
   lastUpdatedTime : string = "";
    
    from component :
    
        getParameter() {
            this.tableLoading = true;
            this.myService.getConParameters().subscribe( (data) => {
              this.lastUpdatedTime = data.createdAt
              this.tableLoading = false;
              }, (_error) => {
                this.tableLoading = false;
              })
          }
    
    To component :
    
    <p class="adjust-space">{{ lastUpdatedTime }} : </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service to share information between two unrelated components, working example below

component a

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { MyServiceService } from './my-service.service';
import { UnrelatedOneComponent } from './unrelated-one/unrelated-one.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [UnrelatedOneComponent],
  template: `
    <app-unrelated-one></app-unrelated-one>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  tableLoading = false;

  constructor(private myService: MyServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getParameter();
  }

  getParameter() {
    this.tableLoading = true;
    this.myService.getConParameters().subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        this.myService.lastUpdatedTime = data.createdAt;
        this.tableLoading = false;
      },
      error: (_error) => {
        this.tableLoading = false;
      },
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

component b

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyServiceService } from '../my-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-unrelated-one',
  template: `
   <p>
    {{ lastUpdatedAt | date }}
  </p>
  `,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
})
export class UnrelatedOneComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myService: MyServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  get lastUpdatedAt() {
    return this.myService.lastUpdatedTime;
  }
}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyServiceService {
  lastUpdatedTime!: Date;
  constructor() {}

  getConParameters() {
    return of({
      createdAt: new Date(),
    });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xby8vx)